# MyBatis - how use a REF CURSOR in MyBatis?

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis, mybatis

Can anyone give an example of the use of REF CURSOR from Oracle using myBatis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mybatis 3 User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/downloads/detail?name=MyBatis-3-User-Guide.pdf&can=3&q=Docs) explains this.  Just search for "cursor".